# Check empty object in Angularjs Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show Login and Logout button according to $rootScope variable. But it show always **Logout** in li tag which mention in below. 
 I do some stuff on some events are:-

After Login:-

```
$rootScope.userData = response.userdata;//response.userdata is Object
```

After Logout:-

```
delete $rootScope.userData;
$rootScope.userData = null;
```

Controller:-

```
console.log($rootScope.userData);//Object {}
```

Html:-

```
<li ng-if="$root.userData == null"><a href="#/login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a></li>
<li ng-if="$root.userData != null"><a href="#/logout"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Logout</a></li>
```

Comment: We need more context, what is `$root`? Can you set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: I need Login or Logout work as toggle according to $rootScope variable. Code in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/clsah/L1qfLo9e/

Answer (score 1):

login `ng-if="!$root.userData.length"`

logout `ng-if="$root.userData.length"`

I recommend you to create a `MainController` and load loggedin data into a model, say `user` and add that `MainController` to your `<body>` tag, so that you can have access to loggedin user everywhere rather than adding this to rootScope.

You can create a `service` that can tell if user is loggedin and return data. In this way you can also have another model called `isAuthenticated` that can have `true` or `false` by checking login status using that service. Then you can only do `ng-if="isAuthenticated"` and `ng-if="!isAuthenticated"`

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show instead of ng-if..

Comment: check above js fiddle link. I have replaced ng-if to ng-show